# excel vba - range.find method

Tags: excel, vba

i have a problem with the following code, the wrong row is returned based on the string searched

PlayerName always exists and is unique with the  named range EventString

but

cell x containing string "tt" will return row number 26 - first row of named range - incorrect

same cell x containing string "ttt" will return row number 35 - correct

```
Private Sub TextBox10_Change()

Dim PlayerName As String
Dim RowNumber As Integer

PlayerName = Label19.Caption

RowNumber = Range(EventString).Find(PlayerName, , Excel.xlValues).Row
Worksheets(wsEclec).Cells(RowNumber, 117).Value = TextBox10.Value

End Sub
```

any help would be much appreciated

richard

edit :

"tt" exists but contents of textbox10 are written to cells "26,117"

if I change "tt" to "ttt" contents of textbox10 are written to cells "35,117"
[the searched table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1QKR.png)

edit 2 :  having posted the picture i've just spotted what's happening

range.find is finding the first partial match so i somehow need to specify an exact match

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your example is not very clear. Could you rather give a simpler version with different strings? e.g in A3 I have Dog and A4 I have cat as we cant see yoru data and replicate it.

Comment: Maybe use `exit` instead of `change`, change is always good, except for this situation.

Comment: @Richard - the `LookAt:=xlWhole` argument of the `Find` method will specify an **exact** match.

Comment: thanks scott, i made a bad assumption that .find was already trying to find an exact match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks all - scott -

i made a bad assumption that .find was trying to find an exact match

this change has done it

```
RowNumber = Range(EventString).Find(PlayerName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to check whether the search text is found or not like the below.

```
Private Sub TextBox10_Change()
Dim PlayerName As String, RowNumber As Integer, rfound As Range

PlayerName = Label19.Caption
Set rfound = Range(EventString).Find(PlayerName, , Excel.xlValues)

If Not rfound Is Nothing Then
    RowNumber = rFound.Row
    Worksheets(wsEclec).Cells(RowNumber, 117).Value = TextBox10.Value
Else
    MsgBox "Search Value Not Found", vbInformation, "No Matching Text Found"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sixth, problem is, i don't need to test to see if the string exists as it definitely does exist. see edit

Comment: Just remove this lines from the given part. (i.e.) Else part (Else
    MsgBox "Search Value Not Found", vbInformation, "No Matching Text Found")